# When queuing an Azure DevOps Pipeline build via the REST API, is it possible to change the "Manual build for [user]" text?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I queue a build in Azure DevOps Pipelines using [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), the build shows up in the build list as `Manual build for [user]` where `[user]` is the name of the user tied to the token with which the API request was made.  Is it possible to replace this with custom text (e.g., `Build for PR#1234` or some such)?

***edit:*** Here's a screenshot of the web UI build list with the `Manual build for [user]` text that I'm looking to change:

[image: screenshot of Azure DevOps Pipelines web UI]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the description text like this :

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "software",
   [string]$projectName = "project",
   [string]$definitionId = "895",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$personalAccessToken  = "xxxxxx"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT)
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }

# Construct the REST URL
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$vstsAccount/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0-preview.8"

Write-Host "Uri :" $uri

$params = 
@"
{
    "definitionId": $definitionId,
    "description": "Create Release from PowerShell Script",
    "artifacts": [],
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "VSTS Trigger",
    "manualEnvironments": null,
    "environmentsMetadata": null, 
    "properties": null, 
    "variables": null
}
"@

Write-Host "Request Body :" $params

# Invoke the REST call and capture the results
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose -Debug

Write-Host "Result :" $result

# This call should only provide a single result
if ($result.count -eq 0)
{
    Write-host "Unable to locate Release Definition Id $definitionId"
}
else
{
    Write-host "Successfully triggered the VSTS release job !!!"
}
```

Comment: It's possible I'm being dense and missing something obvious, or maybe `5.0-preview.8` works differently than `5.0` (the URLs look fairly different), but `"reason"` seems to appear as `"manual"` in the response no matter what I send and `"description"` doesn't seem to have any effect or appear in the response.

Comment: can you attached screenshot where exactly you want to change text.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Ok got it. In release pipeline there is 'Release name format' under Options tab. Where you can change the text.
For build pipeline there is 'Build number format' option available. But i think you can use combination of tokens, variables, and underscore characters in this area to create custom text. May be this link can help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Unfortunately, the build number is way off to the side, after the `Manual build for [user]` bit, so far less visible.